# Arraylist in for loop then in if statement cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment and have this code throw an error that it cannot find a symbol

The arraylist is declared outside of the method and it is working in the for loop just before the if-statement.

I am trying to search the arraylist for a last name of an employee and then give return the index to the main method for further processing.

```
public int searchEmployee(String lastN)
 {
 int noName = 0;
 int lastNIndex = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++)
 {

  if (employeeList(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastN))
  {
    lastNIndex = i;
  }  
  else
  {
    i = noName;
  }
}

lastNIndex = noName;  
return lastNIndex;

exit status 1
 Directory.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  if (employeeList(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastN))
      ^
symbol:   method employeeList(int)
location: class Directory
1 error
```

Comment: `employeeList.get(i)`

Comment: `employeeList(i)` should be `employeeList.get(i)` - have you considered searching backwards? Then you can return the *first* match. And what on earth are you doing in your `else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use method **get** to retrieve the element at the specified position in the list. For more info see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-

Fixed version of your code:

```
public int searchEmployee(String lastN) {
    int noName = 0;
    int lastNIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {

        if (employeeList.get(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastN)) {
            lastNIndex = i;
        } else {
            i = noName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList searches with

```
get(i);
```

https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-get-method-example/

Answer (score 0):

try employeeList.get(i) instead of employeeList(i)